# How can i create this user interface in CN1?

Tags: codenameone

I want to know how i can build this user interface in Codename One? I tried to use TableLayout but it seems to be complex. Can you help me with that? Every cell on the image must be a Container. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad layout for a phone and would be cramped in a tablet too. Having said that table layout is pretty easy. You can also use the GUI builder but I think table layout would be easier, you just need to understand spanning. I implemented one approach for this but didn't finish the whole thing since it takes some work. You can also use other approached e.g. giving the row/column constraint explicitly etc...

```
// creates the first row of tables and the second row table
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 9 ; iter++) {
    // this method should create the container with the blue box around it
    hi.add(createBox());
}
// I use a blank label as a "filler" and span it over the rest of the row
hi.add(tl.createConstraint().horizontalSpan(7), new Label());

// 3rd row box and spacing
hi.add(createBox());
hi.add(new Label());

// 3rd row boxes and first box of 4th row
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 7 ; iter++) {
    hi.add(createBox());
}

hi.add(new Label());
hi.add(createBox());

// this would place the container with the content in the center
hi.add(tl.createConstraint().
    horizontalSpan(4).verticalSpan(6), createContent());

hi.add(createBox());
```